# Partial view is not rendering within the main view it's contained (instead it's rendered in it's own page)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view that is contained in a simple index view.  When I try to add a new object to my model and update my partial view to display that new object along with existing objects the partial view is rendered outside the page that it's contained?

I'm using AJAX to update the partial view but what is wrong with the following code?

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class BoringStoreContext 
{
         List<Product> results = new List<Product>();

         public BoringStoreContext() 
         {
             Products = new List<Product>();
             Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 1, Name = "Sure", Price = (decimal)(1.10) });
             Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 2, Name = "Sure2", Price = (decimal)(2.10) });
         }
         public List<Product> Products {get; set;}
}

public class ProductIndexViewModel
{
    public Product NewProduct { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml View:

```
@model AjaxPartialPageUpdates.Models.ProductIndexViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index_AddItem", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "productList" }))
{ 
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
    </div>
}

<div id='productList'>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("ProductListControl", Model.Products); }
</div>
```

ProductListControl.cshtml Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<AjaxPartialPageUpdates.Models.Product>

<table>
    <!-- Render the table headers. -->
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Render the name and price of each product. -->
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Price)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        BoringStoreContext db = new BoringStoreContext();
        ProductIndexViewModel viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel
        {
            NewProduct = new Product(),
            Products = db.Products
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Index_AddItem(ProductIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BoringStoreContext db = new BoringStoreContext();
        db.Products.Add(viewModel.NewProduct);

        return PartialView("ProductListControl", db.Products);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing a script include. In this context, you will need jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min ajax to render the partial view correctly.

Comment: Yep, I was totally missing the script include.  After I added it worked fine.  Thanks!

Comment: @JaJ where and how are you adding the script? I'm following the same example that you are following. I added these two lines at the top of `Index.cshtm` and `ProductListControl.cshtml`:


`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` and 


`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`


But this still doesn't work

Comment: @JaJ and also, what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The method `Html.RenderPartial` actually renders directly to the response stream. This a special method that is available for performance reasons and it should not be used in everyday page rendering scenarios. Instead you should use the `Html.Partial` method as shown below:

```
<div id='productList'>
    @Html.Partial("ProductListControl", Model.Products)
</div>
```

`Html.Partial` returns an `MvcString` which you can output directly to your view.

Comment: The question is asking for an ajax response not an inline rendered partial view.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the DisplayFor and use @item.Name instead; like this;

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <td>@item.Name</td>
}
```

This worked for me.